# Jade compilation error in WebStorm 7

Tags: pug, webstorm

I am seeing this Jade error since I updated from WebStorm 6 to 7. Jade version is 0.35.

This is the route:

```
exports.index = function (req, res) {

  var model = // get collection;
  res.render('index', {data: model});
};
```

The Jade compilation error I am seeing in the index.jade inside WebStorm 7

```
C:\Docs\Source\Projects\unicorn\src\node_modules\jade\bin\jade:163
          throw e
                ^
TypeError: index.jade:11
    9| 
    10| block content
  > 11|   for item in data
    12|     div #{item._id} #{item.view_key}
    13| 
    14|   form(role='form')

Cannot read property 'length' of undefined
    at jade.debug.unshift.lineno (eval at <anonymous> (C:\Docs\Source\Projects\unicorn\src\node_modules\jade\lib\jade.js:152:8), <anonymous>:139:31)
    at eval (eval at <anonymous> (C:\Docs\Source\Projects\unicorn\src\node_modules\jade\lib\jade.js:152:8), <anonymous>:176:4)
    at C:\Docs\Source\Projects\unicorn\src\node_modules\jade\lib\jade.js:153:35
    at C:\Docs\Source\Projects\unicorn\src\node_modules\jade\bin\jade:154:17
    at C:\Docs\Source\Projects\unicorn\src\node_modules\jade\node_modules\mkdirp\index.js:38:26
    at Object.oncomplete (fs.js:107:15)
```

Page renders correctly in browser. This seems like a WebStorm IDE issue. Any suggestions?

Comment: Perhaps `data` or `item` are being reserved. Try renaming them to something else

Comment: ...and isn't it supposed to be `each item in data`?

Comment: Hi Mike, each or for works as expected; I tried both. I renamed data property to something else, same issue.

Comment: It would be very beneficial if you add a bit more details about your collection implementation which is passed over the template as `data` parameter. Is it an array or some customer array-like implementation?

Answer (score 0):

You get this error because WebStorm Jade watcher tries to compile the file and cannot find you're variable "length" (are you using local variables?)

So in order to solve this you should:

Edit WS watcher: File->Settings->Tools->File Watchers->DClick on jade
   there you can insert in the field "Arguments" somthing like this:
    -O "{length:24,another_var:{state:1,string:\"name\"}}"